# String.length() function

Tags: java

Can somebody please explain me this behavior of java.

```
class StringLength {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "Hi! This is me.";
        int length = str.length();
        System.out.println("String length is :" + length);
        System.out.println("String length for second case is :".length());

    }
}
```

The output of code is :

String length is :15

34

First `println` statement gives output as 15. That's ok, but what about second one?? How second one is even syntactically correct, because concatenation operator for java is "+" not ".". can anyone please explain me this output.

Comment: That's the kind of questions you should be asking yourself.

Comment: What do you think `System.out.println("I am an alien, ".concat("please don't shoot me"));` will do?

Comment: No you are wrong. it gives me 15 & 34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `length()` method on the string `"String length for second case is :"` The characters in that string add up to 34.

It would be the same as saying

> String s = "String length for second case is :";
>
> System.out.println( s.length() );

Answer (score 3):

The second one is synonymous to:

```
String str2 = "String length for the second case is:";
System.out.println(str2.length());
```

Answer (score 3):

When running this code, I get

```
String length is :15
34
```

Sure, the length of `"Hi! This is me."` is 15.  But `"String length for second case is :"` is a `String` literal, which can be treated as a `String` object, and a method can be called on it too.  There is no concatenation; just a method call on a string literal.  Its length is 34.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("String length for second case is :".length());
```

prints the length of the string `"String length for second case is :"` which is 34.

Answer (score 2):

The second one calls method of the string literal "String length for second case is :".

It's equivalent to:

```
String str2 = "String length for second case is :";
System.out.println( str2.length() );
```